# How to write javaDoc snippet

Tags: java, javadoc

I need to write few examples of how to use constructor in my java documentation. Is there any tag like @Example so when I go to see constructor detail I can see example?

Comment: I don't know any @-tag but you can use `<pre></pre>`. This changes the font and uses the whitespaces.

Comment: Or <code></code>

Comment: Pre will solve my problem. Thank you very much.